Image of an electron
Suppose we are trying to see the image of an electron with a microscope. Is it possible? And if it's possible then what do we see? A point at a time, or a blurry spot, or something else?

An "image" is formed from lots of light rays leaving the same object.  For instance, when your eye forms an image of a symbol on your computer screen, like this symbol,
$$ \sum $$
what's happening is that the lens of your eye is taking light traveling in a particular direction and sending all of that light to a particular place on your retina. At that place, there's a light-sensitive nerve cell, which (in this case) tells your brain "bright" or "dark."  Your brain then takes all of those nerve impulses and constructs a map of the light places and the dark places, which you interpret as an image.
If you want light to interact with "an electron," which might be free and floating in space, you can only do it once.  If your electron scatters the incident light, the electron must also move to conserve momentum.  In that case, the electron will be somewhere else, and the next photo will be scattering from a different location.  You don't get a coherent image if the incident light isn't sent in repeatable directions.
If you'd like to interact repeatably with an ensemble of electrons, perhaps held in place by some atomic nuclei, you can do that.  But you'll wind up getting a map of the structure which holds the electrons in place. Here are some neat pictures.

Thank you this is a realy nice explanation .

You can't see an electron with a microscope.

a little red ball with a minus sign on it ??
